# Drop Down Menu Using jQuery slideDown

Tags: jquery

Hi Friends I am working on simple drop down menu using jQuery When I mouse enter on the menu then the sub-manues will appear with use of `slideDown(2000)` and when I mouse out then same will `slideUp(2000)`. Now the problem is if user mouse enter the main menu  and suddenly mouse out then as per my code the slide effect open entire and then close. I just want when user mouse out from menu the sub menu will slideUp no need to full open ... For your reffrence i have mentioned my code below

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
/*Navigation Code*/
$('#mainNav nav ul li').mouseenter(function(){

    $(this).children('ul').slideDown(200);
    })
$('#mainNav nav ul li').mouseleave(function(){

    $(this).children('ul').slideUp(200);
    })
$('#mainNav nav ul li > ul li ul').parent('li').children('a').css({background: 'url(images/navArrow.png) 184px 18px no-repeat'});

/*Navigation Code Ends*/
});
```

I think `stop()` will help but when I use it my code stops working

Please help me guys.. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to add `.stop()` and it seemed to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EjnHQ/

Like this:

```
$('#mainNav nav ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideDown(200);
});

$('#mainNav nav ul li').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().slideUp(50);
});
```

I would suggest making the `slideUp` pace faster than the `slideDown`.

If for some reason it still doesn't work for you try to add `.stop(true)` or `.stop(true, true)`,
something like this:

```
$('#mainNav nav ul li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
});

$('#mainNav nav ul li').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
});
```

The `True` parameters are used to also clear all queued animations.

Also don't forget `;` at the end of the commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
don't use slideup when mouse out. just hide(); its working fine. example.

**on mouse over:**
--------------------------------------
$("#btnmenu").hover(function(){
   $("#menu").slideDown();
}); 


**on mouse out** 
--------------------------------------
$("#btnmenu").mouseout(function(){
    $("#menu").hide();
});
```